# Combining CSS matrixes

Tags: css, matrix, css-transforms, matrix-multiplication

I am attempting to combine two css 3d transforms from one being applied to a parent and one being applied to a child to a single unified one being applied to the child to increase performance. So, my question is this: what am I missing in the below calculation.

```
parent {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateY(50vh) translateZ(-50vh) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

```
                                     +
```

```
child {
    transform: translateZ(-100vh) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```
                                 and I got
```

```
combined {
    transform: translateY(50vh) translateZ(-150vh) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

What went wrong when I added the matrixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not sum similar transforms. You need to concatenate all of them.

Well, there are special cases, but most of the time this is true

The result would be

```
child {
transform: translateY(50vh) translateZ(-50vh) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) 
           translateZ(-100vh) rotateX(90deg);
```

}

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Also, thank you for teaching me something new about css: that you can have multiple of the same transforms in one statement. The more you know....